# I've unlocked my radio but it keeps needing to be reset again!

Tags: honda, audio, accord

I have an 03 Honda Accord EX non navigation radio. I've unlocked my radio by holding down the 1 and 6 and also the power button. I know the code number and I entered it and the radio comes on but after 2 to 3 minutes it turns back off again. The reason why the radio got reset in the first place was I needed a jump-start a few days ago. I've been having some minor issues with the battery/ the terminals not 100% sure on what's going; no one has been able to pinpoint it yet. This is quite a nuisance, please help!!!!

-J

✌️

Answer (score 2):

You should check the supply fuses for the radio.

There should be two, one for the memory ie a permanent supply and the other switched by the keys...

If the permanent one is blown then it usually causes the radio to loose the settings...